# glmer and warning message and random effect

Tags: r, regression, logistic, lme4-nlme

I have a data set that I expect there to be some variability among individuals; therefore, I chose to include `ID` as a random effect in the `glmer` model. However, when I run the model I get the following warning:

```
model.5 <- glmer(R0A1 ~ Dist_MP + (1|ID), data=secondorder, family=binomial)

Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

If I remove the random effect then the warning doesn't appear; therefore, I would assume that there is not enough variability among individuals (`ID`) for a random effect to be needed. Would you remove the random effect and just run a glm model? Also, how does the `family=binomial` code model the 0's and 1's in a data set? Does it consider 1's as the event?

```
Summary output from glmer model:

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum
  likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: R0A1 ~ Dist_MP + (1 | ID)
   Data: secondorder

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 39451.7  39476.5 -19722.8  39445.7    28693 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0876 -1.0372  0.2758  0.9567  1.7543 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 28696, groups:  ID, 45

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.679e-01  1.505e-02   11.16   <2e-16 ***
Dist_MP     -1.559e-03  8.771e-05  -17.77   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)
Dist_MP -0.614
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you remove the random effect are you using `glm` rather than `glmer` ?  Can you show the output of `summary` ?

Comment: ... and yes, 1's are considered the event.  The log-odds of the response equaling 1 are given by appropriate combinations of the parameters.

Comment: Ben, after reviewing the code and summary output I would have to assume that the warning is due to the random effect as the variance is zero and the standard deviation is zero. My assumption is that there's not enough variability among animal IDs for the random effect to be necessary. What is your opinion on that? In addition, is there an easy way to output the AICc values for model selection? Is this another package?

Comment: Variance of zero is strange. Check the plots and summary statistics.

Comment: Also, is there a way to retrieve standardized coefficient estimates under the glmer coding sequence? In SAS, you can add STDCOEF to the end of the generalized linear mixed model and retrieve the standardized coefficient estimates for comparison amongst the variables estimated.

Comment: (1) you can't automatically standardize the coefficient estimates, but you can easily: `model5.C <- update(model5, . ~ scale(Dist_MP) + (1 | ID))` which might very well make the warning go away. If log-likelihood is the same, then the models are equivalent. (2) RE variance of zero is actually not terribly surprising in general, but is somewhat surprising for this size data set.  Reasons to believe that individuals are self-regulating/among-individual var is *less* than expected from large Poisson samples?

Comment: @BenBolker, thank you for your response. The analysis that I'm conducting is a resource selection function to evaluate the use (animal location) vs. an available sample (random locations). This results in a binary response (value =  1 for animal location and value = 0 for random location). At each location, I extracted distance values to different habitat types to evaluate non-random resource selection. I've conducted a few different resource selection analyses before but have never came across the situation where my variance is zero for a random effect. Do you have any recommendations for

Comment: this situation? Again, I would've assumed there to be some variability among individuals. Lastly, what package/code do you recommend for retrieving AICc estimates?

Comment: @BenBolker I re-ran my global model and used the scale function as you suggested: results<-glmer(R0A1~scale(Dist_MP)+scale(Dist_MPHW)+scale(Dist_HW)+scale(Dist_YP)+ 
                 scale(Dist_AG)+scale(Dist_Shrub)+scale(Dist_CountyRoad)+
                 scale(Dist_PrimaryRoad)+scale(Dist_SecondaryRoad)+scale(Dist_TertFireRoad)+
                 (1|ID)+(1|Year_),data=secondorder,family=binomial)

Comment: The scaling eliminated the re-scaling variable warning message.

Comment: Do you get the same likelihood and the same `VarCorr(fit)` as before (I would expect so)?  Do you consider your problem solved by this?  I believe that rescaling is exactly what the warning is trying to tell you to do ...

Comment: @BenBolker...yes I got the same likelihood and VarCorr(fit) as you expected. Scaling the variables completely eliminated those warning messages. The problem is solved! Thank you!

Comment: @BenBolker...one other question associated to my earlier point about STDCOEF in SAS vs. in R generalized linear mixed model. Is there a way to make comparisions as to which variables are more important than others? For example, does an animal prefer one habitat type greater than another? The currently scaling approach provides the following estimates:

Comment: results<-glmer(R0A1~scale(Dist_MP)+scale(Dist_MPHW)+scale(Dist_HW)+scale(Dist_YP)+scale(Dist_AG)+scale(Dist_Shrub)+scale(Dist_CountyRoad)+scale(Dist_PrimaryRoad)+scale(Dist_SecondaryRoad)+scale(Dist_TertFireRoad)+(1|ID)+(1|Year_),data=secondorder,family=binomial)
> summary(results)